# How to code Regular Expression with an IF ELSE function

Tags: html, regex, web-scraping

I am trying to build a scraper to extract key metrics from a website. One of the metrics is to find the Model number of the products on the website. I am using Outwit as the base program but I'm now stuck when it comes to some exceptions in the sites source code.

Here is an example of the source code:

```
var zx_description = "Test Dress<br/><br/>Model: Nice01j<br/>
```

Where the information I am looking to extract is: `Nice01j`

The issue is that for some products the word Modell is spelled Model and also that the end of the actual model name/number does not always end with a row break but in some cases the code might look like this:

```
var zx_description = "Test Dress<br/><br/>Model: Nice01j";
```

I have managed to create the RegEx before the Modell number as below:

```
/var zx_description[\s\S]+?Modell:/
```

So now Im looking to alter it so that it also takes in consideration that the spelling might be Model with just one "l".

Also the second part is to create a RegEx for the capturing of te info after the actual Model name which in should be something like:

```
IF: < br comes before "; then < br ELSE ";
```

Is this possible to state in a Regular Expression and if so how would I do that?

Comment: ``/Modell?/`` matches both "model" and "modell".

Comment: For the second part, just use a non-capturing group: ``(?:<br/>|";)``.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your fast reply. The second suggestion does not seem to be working. I tried without grouping them ie. using `<br/>|";` and this picks up the right info in the first example, however it does not pick up "; in the case of the second example.

Comment: What programming language is in use here?

Comment: I am using a program called **Outwit Hub**. It is a "non-programmer" tool for people like me without deep programming skills. I am not sure about which programming language is in use but I will try to find out.

Comment: What I find strange is that if I use `<br` on a page with this in the code it works fine. If I use `";` on the same page it does of course not populate what I want. The same goes for the second source example which has the ending ";. In this case if I use `";` it works and using `<br` does not work. However if I use the OR function as in `<br/>|";` in the first example it works but not in the second example. It is like it does not "enter" what is stated after the "OR sign"

Answer (score 0):

Based on your use of [\s\S] it looks to me like you need to run through a regular expression tutorial.  For your question, specifically focus on optional items and capturing groups.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip graywh. Just as you noticed I am a novice in this field.

Comment: '[ABC]' matches any sequence of letters as long as it contains only 'A', 'B' or 'C', so it matches 'ABC', but also 'BBBCAC'. \s means any white space and '\S' means any non-white space, so your group matches everything. '[\s\S]' can just be replaced by the anything specifier which is '.'. It only works because you're using non-greedy match.

Comment: `[\s\S]` is the correct way to emulate dot-matches-all mode in JavaScript. Other regex flavors have an option to make the `.` also match newlines, but JavaScript doesn't. So that's no reason to be criticizing anybody.